# Laravel - Eloquent model not firing an event

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I am working with https://github.com/JosephSilber/bouncer package. I am currently working under making it working with UUID instead of typical int identifers. From issues I found how to do this: https://github.com/JosephSilber/bouncer/issues/256.

The problem is that creating a role/ability ends up with error:

> SQLSTATE[23000]: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'id', table 'db.dbo.roles'; column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails. (SQL: insert into [roles] ([name], [title], [updated_at], [created_at]) values (Users, User, 2021-07-08 15:22:46.247, 2021-07-08 15:22:46.247))

I have uuids in my database instead of ids, so I created a boot method in my custom Role/Ability Model to catch a `creating` event like so:

```php
trait BouncerUuidTrait
{
    public static function boot(){
        parent::boot();

        // NEVER REACHING HERE
        self::creating(function ($model) {
            $model->incrementing = false;
            $model->{$model->getKeyName()} = Str::uuid()->toString();
        });
    }
}
```

Example of my custom Role class:

```php
use Silber\Bouncer\Database\Role as BouncerRole;

class Role extends BouncerRole
{
    use BouncerUuidTrait;

    public $incrementing = false;

    protected $fillable = ['id', 'name', 'title'];
}
```

Logic for creating a role:

```php
        $role = Bouncer::role()->firstOrCreate([
            'name' => LDAPInterface::LDAP_GROUP_WCR_USERS,
            'title' => 'User',
        ]);
```

And here is my migration from bouncer package(with uuids):

```php
public function up()
    {
        Schema::create(Models::table('abilities'), function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->uuid('id')->primary();
            $table->string('name');
            $table->string('title')->nullable();
            $table->bigInteger('entity_id')->unsigned()->nullable();
            $table->string('entity_type')->nullable();
            $table->boolean('only_owned')->default(false);
            $table->json('options')->nullable();
            $table->integer('scope')->nullable()->index();
            $table->timestamps();
        });

        Schema::create(Models::table('roles'), function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->uuid('id')->primary();
            $table->string('name');
            $table->string('title')->nullable();
            $table->integer('level')->unsigned()->nullable();
            $table->integer('scope')->nullable()->index();
            $table->timestamps();

            $table->unique(
                ['name', 'scope'],
                'roles_name_unique'
            );
        });

        Schema::create(Models::table('assigned_roles'), function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
            $table->uuid('role_id')->index();
            $table->bigInteger('entity_id')->unsigned();
            $table->string('entity_type');
            $table->bigInteger('restricted_to_id')->unsigned()->nullable();
            $table->string('restricted_to_type')->nullable();
            $table->integer('scope')->nullable()->index();

            $table->index(
                ['entity_id', 'entity_type', 'scope'],
                'assigned_roles_entity_index'
            );

            $table->foreign('role_id')
                  ->references('id')->on(Models::table('roles'))
                  ->onUpdate('cascade')->onDelete('cascade');
        });

        Schema::create(Models::table('permissions'), function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
            $table->uuid('ability_id')->index();
            $table->uuid('entity_id')->nullable();
            $table->string('entity_type')->nullable();
            $table->boolean('forbidden')->default(false);
            $table->integer('scope')->nullable()->index();

            $table->index(
                ['entity_id', 'entity_type', 'scope'],
                'permissions_entity_index'
            );

            $table->foreign('ability_id')
                  ->references('id')->on(Models::table('abilities'))
                  ->onUpdate('cascade')->onDelete('cascade');
        });
    }
```

Comment: I believe this is similar to [this issue](https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/2536) on the delete event. You're never actually instantiating a model, so no events can be fired.

Comment: To try to maybe clarify: `Bouncer::role()->firstOrCreate()` is just query builder (when hitting the "create" part), you're never actually getting a model instance. So it would make sense that no *model* events are fired.

Comment: This is responsible for instanting a model if I am right: `Bouncer::role()`. So how should I create a model to trigger `creating` event?

Comment: No, accessing a relationship is still just query builder. Notice you're using the method statically, not like `$r = new Role; $r->create()` where you would actually have an model instance.

Comment: `$role = new Role(); $role->name = LDAPInterface::LDAP_GROUP_WCR_USERS; $role->title = 'User'; $role->create();` This code doesn't trigger either

Answer (score 0):

In order to fire model events, a model must be instantiated.

### Basic Model Example

For a single model (without relationships), this is as simple as opting for one create syntax over another:

**Does Not Fire Model Events**

```php
Model::create([
  'field' => 'value
]);
```

**Fires Model Events**

```php
$model = new Model;
$model->field = 'value;
$model->save();
```

### Relationship Example

For relationships, we follow a similar syntax.

**Does Not Fire Model Events**

```php
Model::related()->create(['field' => 'value']);
```

**Fires Model Events**

```php
$model = Model::find(1);

$related = new Related;
$related->field = 'value';

$model->related()->attach($related);
```

### Summary

You'll notice the main difference between the two types are the use of `static` method calls vs actually creating a `new` model first. The `create` and similar methods are handy shortcuts, but you need to be aware of the tradeoffs like these.

Comment: I understand, but code like `$role = new Role(); $role->title = 'User'; $role->save();` does not change anything in my case. Event is also not fired there.

Comment: Should your listener be `self` or `static`? https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent#events

Comment: I can't see what the difference it would make, but let's say self, like in other examples.

Comment: Are you sure the `boot` method is being called? I can't seem to replicate this..

Comment: Yes I am sure that boot method is executed. I checked by adding random `var_dump(__CLASS__)` before catching an event.